# API calls from Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**OBJECTIVE**

I want to retrieve JSON(P) data from tools I use (Quickbooks, Zoho, etc.) for custom reporting in Google Spreadsheets. Object Parameters (e.g "Account.name", "Account.birthday") would be listed across Row 1 in Spreadsheets and data would be dumped into the columns.

I know I can run javascript scripts in Google Spreadsheets via their script editor and I know *some* javascript - at least enough for array and object manipulation (not familiar with APIs)...

**QUESTION**

1. I think I can make JSONP requests for x-domain API requests (via
   HTTPS) - am I correct?
2. For private APIs, I'll have to pass in an Private API Token - can I
       prompt a user to insert their API key and then make a request? As a
       result, no API keys will be stored permanently. Is this okay?
3. I'm pretty sure I've seen some websites that have API keys in their URL (soundcloud?) - I thought that having visible API keys is dangerous (someone can steal your key and abuse the company's servers). Am I wrong in my thinking?

Once again, I am fairly new to programming so feedback (and reading resources) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can prompt the user with a prompt [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), a custom HTML dialog, or a sidebar.  Apps script can make either an HTTPS GET or POST request with [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))  Authenticating usually requires the ability to handle a callback request.  A custom dialog or sidebar can *not* do that.  You *could* publish the script that is bound to the spreadsheet, and the url associated with the published script could handle the callback.

Comment: @SandyGood Thank you for this information!

If a script is published (and has it's own URL for proper callbacks/authentication), what happens if multiple people run the script simultaneously? Are all API calls going back to a single URL? Would this cause any conflicts/issues?

Comment: If you run into problems, Apps Script does have a [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/)  I'm not sure how much traffic you are expecting.  Even with functions getting called rapidly in succession, there are ways that you can store temporary data to avoid collisions.  There are situations where you'd need a strategy to avoid something like rows in a spreadsheet getting set out of order, or the same key value being assigned to multiple users.  But dealing with that is specific to the use case.